# Is there any performance issues dividing async functions for DB handling?

Tags: async-await, objection.js

Is there any performance changes between these two block of codes

```
const supplier = await Supplier.query()
                 .findById(1)
                 .throwIfNotFound()

await supplier.$query().delete()
```

```
await Supplier.query().findById(1).throwIfNotFound().delete()
```

From what I have understood, the second code is better because there is only a single waiting code block
unlike the first which has two async methods. But for this example in the first block of code, since the execution is fast, the await method will not pause the find query, but continue executing immediately for both methods.

Is this assessment correct? If not which one is better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if the first one would be some nanoseconds slower, it will never be any performance bottleneck in your app.

So write which ever is more clear to you.